# 'optgroup' element label isn't reading the string after space

Tags: javascript, html

Below when the code runs label doesn't read the string 'data' after space. I have tried with some CSS on optgroup element but it didn't make any change on its label.

```js
var data = "Names of Meters";
var func = function() {
  var options = 
      "<optgroup label=" +data+ ">"
        +'<option value="Meter1" >' + "Temperature" + '</option>'
        +'<option value="Meter2" >' + "Wave" + '</option>'
        +'<option value="Meter3" >' + "Wind Speed" + '</option>'
      + "</optgroup>";
  return options
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = func();
```

```html
   <select type='list' name='sensors' id ="demo" multiple></select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the quotation marks of label name.

```js
var data = "Names of Meters";
var func = function() {
    // here, surround the 'data' with single quotation marks
    var options = "<optgroup label='" + data + "'>"
        + '<option value="Meter1" >' + "Temperature" + '</option>'
        + '<option value="Meter2" >' + "Wave" + '</option>'
        + '<option value="Meter3" >' + "Wind Speed" + '</option>'
        + "</optgroup>";
    return options;
};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = func();
```

```html
<select type='list' name='sensors' id ="demo" multiple></select>
```

> But why is it still reading until the white space even if without quotation marks?

Because quotes around attribute values are not necessary. For example, you can use

```
<input value=4 />
```

However, sometimes it is necessary to use quotes (like this case). If the value contains a whitespace, it'll not display correctly.

See [HTML Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp)

Comment: But why is it still reading until the white space even without quotation marks?

Comment: Thank you for you reply.

Answer (score 1):

Now with ES6 features, you don't have to add HTML like this line by line, you can use inverted comas instead:

````js
var data = "Names of Meters";
var func = function() {
  var options = 
      //inverted coma ``` and ${...} are used for joining data
      `<optgroup label="${data}">
          <option value="Meter1" >Temperature</option>
          <option value="Meter2" >Wave</option>
          <option value="Meter3" >Wind Speed</option>
        </optgroup>`;
  return options
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = func();
````

```html
<select type="list" name="sensors " id="demo" multiple></select>
```